# Jpa Specification to find subset of field's value

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, spring-data-jpa, kotlin

I am writing a webapp using Spring Data JPA on persistence layer, more specifically, my DAOs extends the `JpaSpecificationExecutor` interface, so I am able to implement some kind of filter; imagine list of `Item`s with several attributes (I omit annotations and other metadata for sake of clarity):

```
data class Item(var tags: MutableList<String>)
```

On my service layer, my filter method looks like this:

```
fun findBy(tagsToFilterBy: List<String>): List<Items> {
    return dao.findAll { root, query, builder ->
        builder.//??
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to retrieve only `Item`s that contain exactly that `tagsToFilterBy`, in other words, `tagsToFilterBy` should be a subset of `Item.tags`.

I know about `isMember(...)` method, but I think that it's usage wouldn't be very pleasant with many tags as it accepts only single "entity" at call. Could you advice me something?

My other question is that whether it is safe to use user input directly in let's say `builder.like(someExpression, inputFromUser)` or I have to put it in `builder.parameter(...)` and then `query.setParameter(...)`.

Thank you for any idea

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to write by myself. I'm not saying that it is pretty, but it is the prettiest one, I could come with:

```
dao.findAll { root, query, builder ->
    val lst = mutableListOf<Predicate>()
    val tagsPath = root.get<List<Tag>>("tags")
    tagsToFilterBy.forEach {
        lst.add(cb.isMember(it, tagsPath))
    }
    cb.or(*lst.toTypedArray())
}
```

This is basically going through the given tags, and checking whether it is a member of tags or not.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use filter and test each element to see if your filter list contains it.

```
val result = dao.filter { tagsToFilterBy.contains(it.tag) }
```

To speed it up, you could force sort your filter list, and maybe use `binarySearch`, but performance improvement (or not) would depend on the size of the filter list.  For example, assuming `tagsToFilterBy` is sorted, then:

```
val result2 = dao.filter { tagsToFilterBy.binarySearch(it.tag) >= 0 }
```

The [Kotlin Collection](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html) page describes each of these extension methods.

Comment: I forgot to mention in the question that I may have more attributes to filter by, that's why I need to use `Specification`

Comment: I posted the code that solved an issue for me, feel free to have a look.